# Consuming SOAP endpoint using Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm creating a AWS Lambda using Quarkus.
My challenge is to consume a broker SOAP.
The broker SOAP classes are already generated by my company on a external dependency.

I'm following the documentation do use Quarkus CFX (https://docs.quarkiverse.io/quarkus-cxf/dev/user-guide/first-soap-client.html)

What I have for tryed for now is this:

The SOAP WSDL Class (this is generated by my company, no Quarkus cfx):

```
@WebService(
    targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
    name = "ISpokesmanServices"
)
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface ISpokesmanServices {
    @WebMethod(
        operationName = "GetListSpokesman",
        action = "http://tempuri.org/ISpokesmanServices/GetListSpokesman"
    )
    @Action(
        input = "http://tempuri.org/ISpokesmanServices/GetListSpokesman",
        output = "http://tempuri.org/ISpokesmanServices/GetListSpokesmanResponse"
    )
    @RequestWrapper(
        localName = "GetListSpokesman",
        targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        className = "br.com.xxxx.pme.core.ws.xxxxx.spokesmanservices.GetListSpokesman"
    )
    @ResponseWrapper(
        localName = "GetListSpokesmanResponse",
        targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        className = "br.com.xxxxxx.pme.core.ws.xxxxx.spokesmanservices.GetListSpokesmanResponse"
    )
    @WebResult(
        name = "GetListSpokesmanResult",
        targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/"
    )
    GetListSpokesmanResultDTO getListSpokesman(@WebParam(name = "communicationChannel",targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/") String communicationChannel, @WebParam(name = "spokesmanId",targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/") String spokesmanId);
```

My configs:

```
br.com.xxxxx.ISpokesmanServices.baseUri=https://...
quarkus.cxf.client.ISpokesmanServices.wsdl = ${br.com.xxxxx.ISpokesmanServices.baseUri}/XXXXXX/Service/SpokesmanServices.svc?wsdl
quarkus.cxf.client.ISpokesmanServices.client-endpoint-url = ${br.com.xxxxx.ISpokesmanServices.baseUri}/XXXX/Service/SpokesmanServices.svc
quarkus.cxf.client.ISpokesmanServices.service-interface = br.com.xxxx.ISpokesmanServices
```

My Lambda:

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class Lambda implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, OutputObject> {

```
@CXFClient("ISpokesmanServices")
ISpokesmanServices spokesmanServices;

@Override
    public OutputObject handleRequest(final SQSEvent event, final Context context) {

        var result = spokesmanServices.getListSpokesman("WEB", "15350650017");
```

When I build my project I get the following error:

```
[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type br.com.xxxxxx.SpokesmanServices and qualifiers [@CXFClient("ISpokesmanServices")]
```

I belive that Quarkus can't instantiate the class for some reason, but it should figure it out no?

Also, I couldn't make it quarkus to generate the classes using my WSDL. For some reason it generate all classes but not the interface to access it. So I decided to use the ones my company uses.

I'm completly clueless about what the problem can be!